# How to open a url using Safari View Controller API in Delphi?

Tags: ios, delphi, safari

I have written a function in my iOS and Android apps to open a url.
I am using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo.
My code was rejected by iTunes Connect, saying below.

> We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect:
> Specifically, the app links out to Safari for 質問票回答画面(display for questionnaire, in Japanese).
>
> Next Steps
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to address all instances of this type of issue.
>
> We recommend implementing the Safari View Controller API to display web content within your app. The Safari View Controller allows the display of a URL and inspection of the certificate from an embedded browser in an app so that customers can verify the webpage URL and SSL certificate to confirm they are entering their sign in credentials into a legitimate page.

I want to follow their recommendation to use
Safari View Controller API for opening url.
However I could not find any information for using Safari View Controller API in Delphi.

My code is below.
How should I revise it for using Safari View Controller API?
*I modified google form url to 'xxxx'.
In addition, I got an 'ios-object-pascal-wrapper' including an 'iOSapi.SafariServices.pas'
But I don't know how should I use it.
I want to know the way for using in Delphi properly.

```
Procedure OpenGoogleForm;
Begin
//  Open URL
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
Intent.setData(StrToJURI('https://docs.google.com/forms/xxxx'));
SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF IOS}
SharedApplication.openURL(StrToNSUrl('https://docs.google.com/xxxx'));
{$ENDIF}
End;
```

Comment: Have your app display a Form with FireMonkey's `TWebBrowser` component on it. See [Mobile Tutorial: Using the Web Browser Component (iOS and Android)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_the_Web_Browser_Component_(iOS_and_Android)) in Embarcadero's documentation.

Comment: @Remy Sure. Now I am trying it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Remy I  add a form with FireMonkey's TWebBrowser following link you teach me. However, an error was occurred saying 'An access violation occurred at address 0000000101152184. (When accessing address 0000000000000134). How should I fix it?

Comment: @Remy I could fix it by my self. Thank you very much for your help!